# SO/SE should activate Google Chrome Frame

Tags: feature-request

## What

Google Chrome Frame (GCF) is basically Google's Chrome as a web control installed inside Internet Explorer. The choice of installing or not is completely up to the user. When activated (by a web page), it renders the web page using the Chrome engines (HTML, JavaScript, etc.). When not activated, it does nothing and lets the default IE engines do the rendering. This has the benefit of retaining complete compatibility for sites which require IE while also supporting sites which use the latest web technologies.

## How

Include an HTTP header or HTML meta tag to activate. Instructions at http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started#TOC-Making-Your-Pages-Work-With-Google-Chrome-Frame

Optionally, notify visitors using IE that they can get the best experience by installing GCF.

## Why

I need to use Internet Explorer for various reasons, but I am also able to use GCF.

The benefit to the SO/SE devs is that with a one-line change to a web page template, they can support Internet Explorer without needing to use HTML/JavaScript workarounds. SO/SE has a large cachet with users. If you guys recommend something, people will listen.

Comment: What exactly is "Google Chrome Frame", and why should the devs care?

Comment: I'm confused. They made some weird extension that a user has to install so that it renders IE pages as Chrome, but it only works if each site adds a silly meta element to their page? Seems absurd. Why in the world doesn't it just render pages that way always?

Comment: @animuson, to avoid breaking intranets that rely on old IE.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - hi. Edited to answer your questions.

Comment: @animuson - Chrome Frame seems to offer the best experience on both sides--complete compatibility with both old-style and new-style web pages for users, and no workarounds required for developers.

Comment: The funny thing is, I discovered today that when you install Google Chrome Frame, a full-blown copy of Chrome itself gets installed in your application data folder. The full path is listed at the special URL (in Internet Explorer) `gcf:about:version'

Comment: then there's no point? Just install chrome

Comment: @Doorknob, could be a system that's locked down to where you can't install anything. You [don't need admin privileges](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started/chrome-frame-faq#TOC-Do-I-need-to-be-an-Administrator-to-install-Google-Chrome-Frame-) to install Chrome Frame.

Comment: @TheCommunity But you do to install chrome? That doesn't make sense. If Chrome Frame installs Chrome, you can install Chrome of course.

Comment: @Doorknob, I guess it installs Chrome if it has admin privileges and doesn't if it uses the non-admin fallback? Not sure...

Comment: Chrome requires admin prviledges for a multi-user install single user installs (beta & dev builds) don't.

Comment: But why do we care about Internet explorer? Any developer worthy of calling themselves a programmer should _**NOT**_ be using IE!

Comment: @ColeJohnson: The SE network doesn't cater to only programmers alone. There are also sites for other area such as cooking.

Comment: As far as I can tell, GCF is just Google WebKit for Internet Explorer. If you are smart enough to know about and use GCF, you might as well just use Chrome!

Comment: @ColeJohnson The point of GCF is not to save people the trouble of installing Chrome, but rather to allow a site (like SO) that requires a modern web browser to still function on machines so locked-down that Chrome cannot be installed. GCF does not require the user to install anything themselves.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Knowing or not knowing about GCF is irrelevant. Half the beauty of the thing is that the right meta tag will trigger a very low key install process for people that have no idea what they are doing and don't even have admin rights to their system. Chances are the users that would be benefiting from it already have it installed, this site just needs to opt-in for these users to get the benefit. Without the site opting-in, the user doesn't benefit from something they probably already have.

Comment: @Caleb as I said previously, you don't need admin rights to install chrome. It installs to your appdata if it can't access program files or if its a beta/Dev build

Answer (score 2):

You see a one-line change to a web template, I see a ton of QA testing right now and then a whole new set of users with weird support issues for the rest of time.

**The benefit also seems extraordinarily limited**: better support for users who can install GCF, but can't install Chrome, and who even know about GCF in the first place.  If you go by the theory that [all new features start at -100 points](https://web.archive.org/web/20160229162228/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx) I don't know that this would make the cut.

I'm also a bit mystified as to why this should require intervention on the server end at all.  If the user already has to install this plugin, why not let them choose which websites to enable it for?  It doesn't seem plausible to want all websites everywhere to change to support this niche.

Comment: This answer only goes to show you don't know how GCF actually works, what it accomplishes, or who's choice it is to use or not use it. I'm sorry but pretty much every point you raise here is contra-indicated by reality.

Comment: @Caleb I freely admit that I might not completely understand GCF.  To judge by others' comments, I'm not the only one though.  Your request might benefit from including more details of the exact problem that GCF solves as there might not be widespread familiarity with it.

Comment: To answer your last paragraph, GCF doesn't want to take over rendering all pages because that might break old websites/intranets/custom corporate applications that were designed to run on IE6/7/whatever. It will take over rendering for pages which ask it to. Basically saying: I want to be rendered by WebKit/V8.

Comment: @Yawar My point was that the choice of which pages to render using GCF can (theoretically) be made by either the user or the server.  GCF appears to prefer that the server decide, and my question is why not expose that choice to users so that they don't have to request changes to servers they don't control?

Comment: In theory, because we don't want to expose users to yet another option. The decision to activate GCF, and the HTML header modification, should ideally be made by the site developer because ostensibly the developer knows what the best rendering engine for their site should be.

Comment: @Yawar Obviously that's more convenient for the user, but literally at the cost of every single webpage having to make that particular decision for them (albeit usually implicitly via inaction).  The top of every site served on SE begins with `<!DOCTYPE html>`, which is explicitly to indicate how the page should be rendered.  Why should another header that essentially says, "I really mean it," be necessary?

Comment: Well, we're not talking about the general case, so I have no comment on that. All I'm saying here is that SO/SE should enable it.

Comment: @Yawar Okay.  My sense is that SO/SE will be more likely to expend resources supporting new technology that's viable in general and over the long-term, so it might be worth addressing those sorts of concerns even if they're not directly applicable, but I could certainly be mistaken.  So far it looks like it's mostly just us in here and not a lot of attention from the rest of the world anyways.  Bounties on meta are never as effective as one would like them to be.

Comment: Well, I guess you're right about the lack of attention part :-) My reasoning was this: if they activate GCF and advise all IE users to use it, then the weight of trying to support IE is off their backs and they can concentrate on using only the latest whiz-bang Web technologies, or whichever ones they need anyway. About the bounty: I'm willing to wait until right before it expires to see if someone says `No, we won't do GCF because of X'. If not, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Yawar You might want to emphasize that more.  "Make life easier by dropping raw-IE compatibility in favor of access via GCF (and it also helps users in this niche situation)" is a very different feature request than "Enable GCF to help niche users, and make IE support easier."  Don't worry too much about the bounty.  Certainly wait until necessary to award it--you paid for the publicity, get it all--but don't feel obliged to choose an answer you don't think merits it.  To judge by the number of upvotes, no one else has been amazed by my answer yet either :)